# Can't download chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have been trying to download Google Chrome. Every time I attempt to download it, my desktop says something like, "You can't download new software, because your current software is having problems." I then get an option that says, "Cannot repair." If anyone can help me asap that would be great!

Comment: open your terminal and type as " sudo apt-get install -f "

Comment: Could you post a link to a screenshot of the window(s) where you're getting the error(s)? This would help us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the Google chrome using the command "sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable". Once it removed successfully, you can get the chrome directly from "http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu" here. If you want to remove the configuration,bookmarks,etc of the existing chrome setup run the command "rm ~/.config/google-chrome/ -rf".

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /tmp 
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb 
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

If you want the 64bit version just replace i386 with amd64

If you encounter any errors simply use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

To run it from terminal use `google-chrome` or hit the super key and search `Google` or `Chrome`

Answer (score 0):

Just type the following commands over the terminal:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

You will now be able to use it.

If you get any additional errors, please post them as a comment to this answer.